# How do i set null in entry box while taking integer input for calculation

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, button, user-input

How do i set null in entry box while taking integer input for calculation

I am confused because I want int else in case of string I know what to do can anyone help me i will be grateful for that

Comment: i am creating gui for calculating the median calculator

Comment: Entry widgets cannot have a null value. They can have an empty string as a value, but not a null value.

Comment: Then how do i keep my entry widget empty for integer value

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "_keep_ [it] empty". If you don't want the user to change it, you can make the widget readonly or disabled. If you want it to appear to be none, you can set it to the empty string.

Comment: I want that by default my entry box should contain none means empty  and then I take user input in integer variable

Comment: Entry widgets can’t contain `None`. An empty string is what represents that the user hasn’t entered anything.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] in order to identify what your problem is.

Comment: I want that by default my entry box should contain none means empty and then I take user input in integer variable here is my code:

Answer (score 0):

> I want int else in case of string

Try this if this is what you want.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

                       
root = tk.Tk()

def testVal(inStr:str, acttyp:int)->bool:
    if acttyp == '1':
        if not inStr.isdigit():
            return False
    return True

ent1 = tk.Entry(root, validate="key")
ent1['validatecommand'] = (ent1.register(testVal),'%P','%d')
ent1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
ent2 = tk.Entry(root, validate="key")
ent2['validatecommand'] = (ent2.register(testVal),'%P','%d')
ent2.grid(row=1, column=0)

def go_to_next_entry(event, entry_list:int, this_index:int)->None:
    next_index = (this_index + 1) % len(entry_list)    
    entry_list[next_index].focus_set()

  
entries = [child for child in root.winfo_children() if isinstance(child, tk.Entry)]
for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e, idx=idx: go_to_next_entry(e, entries, idx))

    
root.mainloop()
```